# How can I use a Integrated IR Receiver IC in a sensor circuit without microprocessors?

Tags: sensor, infrared

I am asked as a term project to design a circuit that is somewhat similar to a park sensor. Let me first say that I am a 2nd year undergrad student, and we are very newly beginning to get into the circuit design stuff.

As for the project, I roughly have what to do in mind, except I have no idea how to utilize the TK-19 sensor. I have provided the link to the datasheet below, I would be very glad if someone can tell me what happens when this thing detects IR radiation, or does not, that is the main question in my mind.

Here's the link to the datasheet: http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheets/restul/305097_DS.pdf

Edit: Let me note that we are only allowed to use diodes(including LEDs and IR LEDs), capacitors, resistors and opamps.

Comment: I don't know where you get that `TK-19` name, when the datasheet is about `TSOP11xx`.

Comment: @Stevenvh thanks for being on top of editing tags, but it was agreed to not use the homework tag here http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/115/what-meta-tags-on-er-should-be-axed and will be going away at some point.

Comment: Fixed the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sensor outputs a high level if it detects the proper input signal, being an IR carrier of 30..56 kHz, depending on the type you chose. Build a IR transmitter which transmits such a carrier. You don't need a microcontroller for that. (I leave it to you to solve this; I'm not going to do your homework completely! :-)) Direct the transmitter to any possible obstacles. If the receiver looks in the same direction it will pick up the reflected signal if you get close enough to the obstacle.
Success!

Comment: When testing the receiver, you can use any off the shelf remote as a transmitter.

Comment: transmitter will have to be slightly more complicated than that.  The receiver has "noise" signal detection and won't respond to a constant square wave at the carrier frequency.

Comment: Basically you have to gate a square wave with a slower square wave. Think to 555 timers.